# How do I simply run a python script from github repo with actions

Tags: python, github, cron, github-actions

I assume it's possible to schedule a python script to run every day for example, from my github repository.

After searching, I've come up with the following main.yml file that resides in the master branch of the repo:

the .py file I want to run resides in another branch; I suppose it doesn't have to if it causes an issue, but the script isn't running either way.

I'm new to a lot of this, and have a funny feeling I'm missing fundamental pieces to get this working.

```
name: py

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "30 11 * * *"    #runs at 11:30 UTC everyday

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: checkout repo content
        uses: actions/checkout@v2 # checkout the repository content to github runner.
      - name: setup python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8 #install the python needed
          - name: Install dependencies
          run: |
            python -m pip install --upgrade pip
            pip install flake8 pytest
            if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
          ref: # branch
            my_other_branch
      - name: execute py script # run file
        run: |
          python my_file.py
```

Comment: As the script is on another branch, you would have to specify the ref branch on the step where you call the script as well (the same way you did to install the dependencies using pip). If the script was on the default branch, you wouldn't need to. Here is a personal workflow you can use as reference: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/03-python-script-workflow.yml

Comment: Is there an error you get when running that workflow?

Comment: Thank you, the script is now attempting to run, having deleted the references to the other branch, moving my .yml file into master branch, and finally the .yml file must be in .github/workflows which it was not before.

However now the script is crashing trying to install packages defined in requirements.txt

Comment: Could you share the repository (if it is public) to check your implementation?

Comment: The build runs successfully now having removed the troubled module from requirements.  Thank you everyone

Comment: Please don't include solutions in the *question* section -- if you've answered your own inquiry, include the solution in the Answers section below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything seems to be working now, the solution was to move my `main.yml` file into `.github/workflows`. I also moved `my_file.py` from alternate branch into the master branch.

One [helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70458458/how-do-i-simply-run-a-python-script-from-github-repo-with-actions#comment124552508_70458458) recommended specifying the ref branch where you run `my_file.py` if `my_file.py` is not located in the default branch.